# Userform ComboBox Enter Event Opens DropDown in Random Location

Tags: vba, ms-word, combobox, userform, sendkeys

I have a UserForm that has a ComboBox as the first item. I expand my ComboBox on the enter event.

When the UserForm initializes and is displayed the ComboBox dropdown selections are expanded in a random location.

I'm sure it expands correctly, however, when the UserForm is centered, the DropDown list is left behind out of position.

Below is what I use to expand the dropdown.
I know adding the SendKeys is an overkill, but I found in other projects the DropDown command doesn't always work.

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Enter()
    ComboBox1.DropDown
    SendKeys "%{DOWN}"
End Sub
```

I got it to work by setting up another SendKey command for ESC before the DropDown command.
Now when the UserFrom initializes it returns a tone in the background. It may have to do with the SendKey commmand happening at a time where the window is not ready for it.

The tone doesn't affect functionality but is annoying and I would like to fix it.

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Enter()
    SendKeys "%ESC"
    ComboBox1.DropDown
    SendKeys "%{DOWN}"
End Sub
```

I tried:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Enter()
    Wait
    SendKeys "%ESC"
    ComboBox1.DropDown
    SendKeys "%{DOWN}"
End Sub

Public Sub Wait()
    CreateObject("Excel.Application").Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
End Sub
```

But I still hear the tone.